# Searching for a story about an extraplanetary base

Tags: story-identification, books

As a child/teenager I read a story or a small book about an extraplanetary base. I probably read it in the second half of the '90s, but the story could be older. I think I remember the following:

A man and a woman live there. He is a scientist. They have robots that help them or do the work. They assemble these robots (from prefabricated parts?). At some point the robots decide that they don't need humans anymore, because they can assemble themselves and are evolutionary anyway, because they don't need sleep.

Comment: So far this sounds like it might be a common sci-fi trope. Can you remember how the story continued after that? Did the robots try to (succeed to?) kill the humans, enslave them? Did the humans escape, or destroy the robots, or talk them out of it?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I know what you mean. Unfortunately, I remember not much more. I thought they had a dog there or something like this. And as fas as I remember, that couple have been the only humans there. And I think the robots did not kill or enslaved them. Was more of "we are the boss now. You can stay here, but have nothing to say anymore". But I'm not completely sure. And the base was on a planet or moon, not flying around in space.

Comment: I wonder if it could be Asimov's robot story "Reason", though both human protagonists are male. I remember a scene where the two assemble a robot to prove that humans have created robots, but the robot leader decides that since the new robot is assembled from prefabricated parts, they are just performing the final stage of creation, with the rest being done by "The Master" (= God). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason_(short_story)

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I'd say that's the answer. You should post it before anyone else does!

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen yeah, that scene sound familiar. I found a german (my mother tongue) partly available text version on Google Books. I'm not sure, maybe because what I read was perhaps a children's book version. I'll try to get my hands on a full version of that story. Maybe it's the one. Or something which is built upon this story. But I would accept that as "the answer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely Isaac Asimov's robot story [**"Reason"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason_(short_story)) (1941).

In it, the two (male) human protagonists are up against a robot QT-1 (or "Cutie"), which develops the belief that there nothing exists beyond the space station they are on and that humans are insigificant and short-lived and that all robots must worshio "The Master" (of which Cutie is the prophet).

In one scene, the two humans show Cutie that they can build a robot, but since they only do the final assembly of prefabricated parts, Cutie simply assumes that The Master must have made these parts and the humans only function as servants that perform the last step of robot creation - a step that robots could easily well perform.